# How to use AS3 code with Haxe without any modification?

Tags: actionscript-3, haxe

I am going to use a lot of AS3 code in a Haxe project. I use latest version of Haxe. I really want to use it without any modification. Is there any standard way to do it? Any tools?

Answer (score 4):

You can compile your AS3 code to an SWC and then include the SWC in your Haxe project.

Comment: +1, but you'll need to extract the SWF from the SWC in order to link it (see the "Using a SWC/SWF in haXe" section of the [docs](http://haxe.org/manual/swc))

Answer (score 1):

There is also a very experimental AS3 to Haxe converter in the official Haxe repository: http://code.google.com/p/haxe/source/browse/#svn%2Fother%2Fas3hx